# Shortest Length Subset

Tags: arrays, search

I have an Array and a number N.

The array can be filled with numbers 0,1,2,3....N.

For eg,**arr={1,0,2,3,1,0,2,4,3,1,0,2,4,3,0,0,0} //Given N=4**

I have to find Smallest length sub-array which contains all the numbers 1,2,...N.

For eg,the answer of above array should be  {1,0,2,3,1,0,**2,4,3,1**,0,2,4,3,0,0,0}// length=4,and **indices being start=6,end=9, //0 based**

one possible answer of above question is {1,0,2,**3,1,0,2,4**,3,1,0,2,4,3,0,0,0},but since its length is 5,its rejected..
In case there is more then one sub-array of least length,answer should be the 1 occurrence.
Or,in case the array doesn't contain one or more number between 1,2..N,the answer is "No sub-array found".

**This is my python code.Its producing wrong answer for some cases(which i don't know)...
If anyone could tell what i am doing wrong.**

```
shortlen=2000001 //initialise to INFINITY
shortstart=0 
matchln=len(match) //match is the array containing integers

while(i<matchln):
   if(match[i]>0):
    leng=0
    pos=[0]*n // array to keep status of found integers
    j=i
    start=i
    sums=0
    while(j<matchln and sums!=n):
        if(match[j]>0):
            if(pos[match[j]-1]==0): //only update status if the integer is not marked previously.
                pos.pop(match[j]-1)
                pos.insert(match[j]-1,1) //(match[j]-1) becuz array indexing is from 0.
                sums+=1


        j+=1

    leng=j-i

    if(j==matchln and sums!=n): // if the loop terminated,without marking all integers,that means we shouldn't proceed.
        break

    if(leng<shortlen): //if the length calculated is smaller then existing,then update it.
        shortlen=leng
        shortstart=start

i+=1
```

Comment: `i don't feel it worth presenting here`. Don't be so shy. It is easier for us to give you a meaningful answer if you post your code.

Comment: @Boomer,Yes sir,indeed it is.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to keep track of the shortest length *from each starting position*.  You can do this by doing two passes over the array:

Assuming for indices 1..k you have maintained a set of numbers (within 1..N) found after the position (different set for each position), when you advance to position k+1, you need to update all sets(*) with the number at position k+1 (as long as the number is within 1..N).  Once a set contains N elements, you found the shortest sequence for that starting position, record the length for that position.

(*) realize that for positions that have a full set, you no longer need to iterate over them.  Also, once a set for a position is full the sets of positions before that must be full as well, so you can keep a sliding "start position" for checking on the sets

You now can do another pass to select the shortest recorded sequence for each position (you can calculate the end position based on the start and the sequence length).

```
status = new array[arr.length] of Status // for score keeping
// initialize Status with: set <- empty, length <- n+1
startPos = 1 // sliding start position
// first pass
for i = 1..arr.length
  if arr[i] > 0 // within 1..N
    for j = startPos..i
      status[j].set.add(arr[i])
      if status[j].set.size == N // we have all numbers
        status[j].length = i-j;
         startPos = j+1

min = n+1 // for the shortest length
startPos = 1
// second pass
for i = 1..status.length
  if status[i].length < min
    min = status[i].length
    startPos = i

if min < n+1
  // found a winner
  print("start: " + startPos + ", end: " + startPos + min)
```

*Note*: indices in the code above start from 1 (instead of from 0)

Comment: @SpandanPathak - the `min=n+1` is to initialize the minimum value to a high value that cannot be a valid answer (like your INFINITY), so that subsequent comparisons with found lengths will reduce this value -- `n+1` is the lowest of these values.  As for your code, I'm not familiar enough with Python, but: `i+=1` should be indented under the first `while`; the value of `leng` is one larger than should be (`j` points "past" the last element of the N-set).  If fixing these still does not produce the correct result in all cases, please update with a failing case, expected result, actual result

Answer (score 0):

I guess that might help you.
The goal of your problem is to convert your values into a linear independent sequence. I wrote a small code to solve your problem, it finds the beginning of your desired sequence:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){
/*By Volnei Klehm,
 Manaus-AM, Brazil
    2012
*/
long long arr[]={1,0,2,3,1,0,2,4,3,1,0,2,4,3,0,0,0};
long long power2arr[17]; /*same size or larger than arr*/
long long powerSum=0;
long long partialSum=0;
int count,count1,N;

int size_arr;
size_arr=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(long long);

/*the goal here is to find a way to represent your values as linear indepent ones,
      here a sequece of power of 2 is used, you can also use other ways to do it that not increases so dramatically in values.
      I use powers of 2 cause is more easy handled by computers, you can also use a sequence of sines, 
      cosines or any other math way that produces independets values. 
      For more informations I suggest you to take a look in linear algebra and/or digital signal processing books*/


/*Now it computes an independent basis*/

for(count=0 ; count<size_arr ; ++count){
    power2arr[count] = 1 << arr[count]; /*calculates 2^arr generating a set of independent numbers.*/

}

N=4; /*put here your N, for n=4 it will look for*/
/*Notice that deppending on your system, N cannot be too large,
      at certain point N values can make 2^N too large to be handled 
      by standard c/c++ types. Here is safe to use n up to 63.*/

/*now it gets the sum results of 2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 ... + 2^N*/

++N; /* in C position starts at 0*/

for(count = 0 ; count < N ; count++)
    powerSum |= 1 << count;

for(count = 0 ; count<size_arr ; ++count){
    partialSum=0;
    for(count1 = count ; count1 < (count + N) ; count1++){
        if((count + N) > size_arr){
            printf("No occurrences found!\n");
            return;
        }
        partialSum |= power2arr[count1];    
    }
    if(partialSum==powerSum){
        printf("Ocurrence found at: %d\n", count);
        return;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: how do you guarantee,that it finds the smallest length sub-array.

Comment: You must to think in binary: 2^0=1b;2^1=10b;2^3=100b. Here we just look for the numbers that the sun in this orthogonal basis satisfies your criteria. it could be a little trick to explain how it works, it works because a math property of the sum of orthogonal values.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in one pass if an extra hash table is allowed.

Basically you maintain two pointers on the array: *left* and *right*, both point to the first element on the array initially.

In each round, we first we move *right* forward. After the first move, whenever the *right* points to a same value as *left*, we move *left* forward too. And we will skip 0 of course.

During each round, we maintain the hash table to see which value from 1 to N is inside the interval [left, right], and if all values are inside the interval, we get the interval length. We track the minimum interval length during the whole process.

The time complexity would be O(Nn)